# Parameterized search in Oracle Coherence returns empty list

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I've got a problem with search in Coherence using IN statement and parameterized list.

Here I'm creating cache with sample data:

```
NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("test-cache");
Some s2 = new Some();
s2.setId(2);
s2.setName("name 2");
cache.put("K2", s2);
Some s3 = new Some();
s3.setId(3);
s3.setName("name 3");
cache.put("K3", s3);
```

Here I'm trying to obtain results using parameterized query:

```
Map<String, ? super Object> map = new HashMap();
map.put("keys", Arrays.asList(new String [] {"K1","K2"}));
Filter filter = QueryHelper.createFilter("key() in :keys", map);
List<Some> list = new ArrayList<Some>(cache.entrySet(filter));
```

System.out.println(filter); prints what appears to be proper filter configuration:

> InFilter(KeyExtractor(extractor=IdentityExtractor), [[K1, K2]])

I'm expecting it to return list with single element with key K2, but it returns empty list.

However, I get proper result if I print key list manually into query string:

```
Filter filter = QueryHelper.createFilter("key() in ('K1','K2')");
```

System.out.println(filter); in this case prints basically the same:

> InFilter(KeyExtractor(extractor=IdentityExtractor), [K1, K2])

Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two filters are not quite the same.  This seems to work:

```
 map.put("keys", new String [] {"K1","K2"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It also work with Set. Looks like it just doesn't like List.